# How to code exponential numbers with powers in R?

Tags: r

I want to multiply a this number 4.193215e+12 with a dataframe. My code is

```
df <- cbind(Dataset = df$Dataset, df[,2:4] * 4.193215e^12
```

However an error appears. What is the proper way to code this number 4.193215e+12 in R?

Comment: You had `+` or `^`?

Comment: Use `4.193215e12`, not `4.193215e^12`. Also missing a `)`.

Comment: 4.193215e+12  this is the number I am trying to multiply

Comment: With a `+` it works well.

Answer (score 1):

While this is found in the not-quite-obvious location  `?NumericConstants` , I am hard-pressed to think of a language in which  `Xe^Y`  is syntactically correct.  Always use either `e` or `^` for powers.